# How to handle array of strings (char **) in ctypes in a 64-bit environment?

Tags: python, arrays, string, 64-bit, ctypes

I'm using ctypes to work with libgphoto2 in Python. The following code succeeds on a 32-bit machine, but fails with a Segmentation Fault on a 64-bit machine (Linux, Ubuntu):

```
import ctypes

gp = ctypes.CDLL('libgphoto2.so')
a = gp.gp_library_version(0)
x = ctypes.c_char_p.from_address(a)
x.value
```

libphoto2, ctypes and python are all from repositories, so I assume that the problem is in my code; I need to consider pointers in a more general way or something like that. `gp_library_version()` returns `const char **`, an array of string constants. Other `gp_*` functions work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that, by default, ctypes assumes that all functions return `int`, which is 32 bits.  But, on a 64-bit system, a pointer is 64 bits, so you're dropping the upper 32 bits from the pointer return value, so you then get a segfault when you try to dereference that invalid pointer.

You can change the expected return type of a function by assigning a type to its `restype` attribute like so:

```
gp = ctypes.CDLL('libgphoto2.so')
gp.gp_library_version.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p)
a = gp.gp_library_version(0)
print a[0].value
```

Comment: `print a[0]` is enough on my Fedora 14 system (python-2.7-8.fc14.1.x86_64).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't annotate anything about functions in ctypes, it is assumed that they return 32bit integers. In 32 bit processes, these integers and pointers are mostly interchangeable - not so for 64 bit builds.

Just doing

```
gp.gp_library_version.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
```

before your call should suffice in this case (You will still need the
`x = ctypes.c_char_p.from_address(a)` line).

Check the API docs on wether you should free this pointer yourself after yu use it (probably yes in this case).